# NFS Server accessing issue

Tags: nfs

This is regarding a file server on domain joined Windows Server 2016 with NFS shares set up. 
Permissions are for All Machines with read/write access. No server authentication is used. Allow unmapped user by access by UID/GID is set up.

There 3 NFS Shares. I'm just having trouble with a share.

For each shared folder, I go to Advanced Sharing and set Everyone to Full Control.

```
[root@nfsclient /]# mount -vvv -t nfs -o timeo=30000 10.180.100.21:/Transfer /mount/NFS    
mount.nfs: timeout set for Wed Jun 10 19:20:32 2020
mount.nfs: trying text-based options 'timeo=30000,vers=4.1,addr=10.180.100.21,clientaddr=10.180.100.11'
mount.nfs: mount(2): Remote I/O error
mount.nfs: Remote I/O error
```

But , I have tried like below. (NFS v3)

```
[root@nfsclient /]# mount -vvv -t nfs -o vers=3 10.180.100.21:/Transfer /mount/NFS
```

No I/O error message. At this time I am creating any folder under /mount/NFS I am getting permission denied.

What is wrong? Please advise.

Thank you very much.

Kind Regards,

Comment: Is there a Firewall in the way, either on one of the endpoints or in the network between?

Comment: no any firewall. I have written above my message.  I'm just having trouble with a share. no issue other shares

Comment: If it was a UNIX/Linux server I'd tell you to go and look in the server logs. On Windows the equivalent will presumably be the event log. Are there any messages of relevance there?

Comment: I have recreated problematic folder. my issue solved :)